# matplotlib legend corrupts font spacing in plot labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

i'm using matplotlib-2.0.0 (with seaborn-0.7.1) on mac os x (backend:  and finding that `plt.legend()` corrupts my plots. here's an example of a plot with a legend (which has messed up font spacings) and the identical plot, without a legend, that looks correct. both generated by this script:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import seaborn as sns
plt.figure()
sns.set_style("white")
plt.plot([1,2,3], [1,2,3], label="foo")
plt.xlabel("X label")
plt.ylabel("Y label")
# with legend
plt.legend(loc="upper left", fontsize=8)
sns.despine()
plt.savefig("test1.pdf")

plt.figure()
sns.set_style("white")
plt.plot([1,2,3], [1,2,3], label="foo")
plt.xlabel("X label")
plt.ylabel("Y label")
# no legend!
sns.despine()
plt.savefig("test2.pdf")
```

[image: messed up plot with legend]
[image: good plot without legend]

the `~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc` settings are:

```
backend : Qt4Agg
font.family: sans-serif
font.sans-serif: Arial, Helvetica
pdf.fonttype : 42
mathtext.fontset : custom
mathtext.sf : Arial, Helvetica
mathtext.rm : Arial, Helvetica
mathtext.it : Arial, Helvetica
```

what is the issue with this? it seems like a bug.

*update:* if i remove the `fontsize` argument to `plt.legend()` the plot looks normal. is there a way to change legend fontsize without having this bug?

Comment: Did you try to use a different font size for the legend? Did you try to use a different backend?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: fontsize 10 makes it go away. it doesn't work with fontsize 8. I don't understand this. Backend makes no difference

Comment: It may be that you haven't got a good version of the font for 8pt installed. You may try to use a different font by putting `plt.rcParams["font.sans-serif"] = "<Font Name>"` below the imports. Does it only appear in pdf output or in png or on screen as well?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: it happens with every font, but only in pdf. png displays correctly. any ideas?